# How can I configure customized / trained vision AI model in the OCI console with APEX?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I need to integrate OCI vision AI customized model with Oracle APEX , I am not able to perform with rest API method, can you please suggest alternative option? How can I import the customized model to Cloudshell / Notebook?